# Optimizing graph searching algorithm

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm working on a project that involves graph searching, and I'm running into efficiency issues. The project contains two lists, A and B, as shown below:

List A: a list of words (ex. ['Hello','world'])

List B: a 2D list of words (ex. [['hi','how'],['are','you'], ...]

I also have a very large graph (over 1,000,000 nodes) of words that connect to each other. The goal of my program is to find the list in B that contains the shortest path to all elements in A. Looking at the example above, this means I'm looking to see dist(hi,hello) + dist(hi,world) + dist(how, hello) + dist(how, world) is less than dist(are,hello) + dist(are,world) + dist(you, hello) + dist(you, world).

I am using networkx in Python. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: the graph is unweighted and undirected. It is a very sparse graph

Comment: Have you considered using another graph library? Networkx is pure-Python, making it rather slow for repeatedly searching through large graphs.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i was about to say floyd warshal, but for 10^nodes, it'd take 10^18 computations

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Sure, what library would you suggest?

Comment: @ma3oun: for now, I simply have a for-loop. I was thinking of possibly memoizing common search paths or splitting the graph into smaller sub graphs. I don't know how effect these options will be

Comment: @ShihabShahriar, thank you for the suggestion. I should note, the graph is not weighted. Do you believe there would be a faster algorithm in this case?

Comment: simple bfs from every node will be O(N^2), better than floyd. If you don't mind me asking, whats your end goal? on one hand I'm curious, OTOH new info this might open up  new possbl solutions

Comment: How about you go to each vertex in A, hopefully there's not too many, do a breadth first search. Then go through each list in B and work out the sum? Or is that what you're doing already?

Comment: @ShihabShahriar. Thank you for your help so far. The set of words in A is a description of a project, and the set of words for each element of B is a description of a student who can possibly solve the project. I want to find the student who is most relevant and capable of solving the project. The graph connects words by similar meaning. Therefore, my idea was to find the student who is semantically closest to the project. Kindly let me know if this helps clarify. Thanks again!

Comment: @Countingstuff. Yes, this is what I am currently doing. ShihabShahriar has described a more optimal algorithm in this case. Thank you for your suggestion, though.